# What awakeFromNib really is?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm just a newbie of Objective C iPhone programming... I see a lot of codes that contains method named "awakeFromNib".. What does it really mean? how and when and where to call this method?
Thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is called for objects (views, controllers, etc.) that are being archived in xib/nib files. This basically means that xib/nib was unarchived, all connections (`IBActions`/`IBOutlets`) for all objects are made and you have a working object graph.

I use it when I have a custom view class that I gave to a certain view in my xib.

Comment: thanks Eimantas.. is that mean that when creating an instance of the viewcontroller, the objects generated are archived at first?

Comment: the objects in nib are archived. The method gets called for each object once the view controller has unarchived nib.

Comment: so when are objects archived or unarchived?

Comment: Objects are archived when you compile the app and build process compiles the xib files or storyboards. Objects are unarchived when you load the nib in the code wither through `UINib` class or sending `UIViewController` `initWithNibName:bundle:` message.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call it. After nib file load, every view inside of it, be it button, UIView or something else, calls `awakeFromNib` from their respective class automatically. You override this method for setup and layout, as you would do with `init` method if you were creating a subview programmatically.

Comment: ahh.. i see.. so it literally means that awakeFromNib is called after everything has been loaded right? thanks Kyr..